# Border radius and overflow hidden fail when CSS filter is applied in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a div with rounded corners in Chrome with overflow set as hidden.

It works as expected: the child content is cut off at the corners.

However, when a filter is applied (in my case, drop shadow), the child content is no longer cut off and has square corners. This happens too with other filters, like blur.

Sample Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="full">
    This div should have rounded corners too.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;

  /* Removes hidden corners in Chrome */
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));

  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.full{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uc1v5nzk/

Firefox renders the element properly when filters are applied.

Is there any elegant fix to this on Chrome, especially when there might be many child elements that may or may not be in the corner?

Chrome Version: Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an absolutely-positioned `::before` element on wrapper seems to fix the bug.

```
.card::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/uc1v5nzk/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is strange behavior and seems a bug in chrome.

You can use a pseudo element to create a layer and apply filter on it:

```css
.card{
  /* Critical CSS */
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.card::before {
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
  position: absoulte;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.full{
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="full">
    This div should have rounded corners too.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to add box shadow, you can replace the `filter: drop-shadow` attribute with `box-shadow` like so:

```
/* filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)); */
box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

In general, for shadow, I rather use box-shadow attribute due to a wide [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).