# Strange behaviour when combine filter and :hover in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Someone can explain why this happened? 
overflow property won't working and corners appears, when I use `transform` and `filter` together.  This is bug or I'm missing something?
Without `filter` all fine. In Mozilla all fine.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<style>
.wrap{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.image{
    background: url(https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-filter: saturate(1.7) brightness(1.05);
    filter: saturate(1.3) brightness(1.07);
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mith1408/nmvozkhd/2/

**UPD.**
Without `transform` but only with `filter`, this bug continue appears.
So, problem not in the combining: `transform` and `filter`.

**UPD2.**
Lookls like this is very old bug, which was fixed but only for passive elements. When you apply `:hover` bug appears again in transition moment.
[Border radius and overflow hidden fail when CSS filter is applied in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191600/border-radius-and-overflow-hidden-fail-when-css-filter-is-applied-in-chrome)

Example from old topic, modified to use `:hover`
https://jsfiddle.net/mith1408/xk1hf3wq/3/

Comment: possible solution:
to separate properties -
 1. apply "filter" for wrapper   
2. "transform" only for image.   

example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mith1408/nmvozkhd/4  

But interesting to find the root of problem.

Comment: I think the bug is related only to the `filter` property, I disabled `transform` changes and the bug is still there

Comment: You right, very strange..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border radius and overflow hidden fail when CSS filter is applied in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191600/border-radius-and-overflow-hidden-fail-when-css-filter-is-applied-in-chrome)

Comment: No this is different topic, because in your example bug appear on passive element.(looks like it was fixed). In my example bug appears when ":hover" pseudo-class applied. and in transition moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem meight be connected with *stacking context*. Both - transform and filter create stacking contexts when applied. This is my first thought.

You can read more here: 
[MDN the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

and here:
[stacking contexts: What they are and how they work](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/09/css-stacking-contexts-wtf/index.html)